# Angular mat application performance issue / lagging issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating an angular application which has a side panel with multiple filter categories, each category is of mat checkbox or mat radio button inside an expansion panel. Along the filter component is a min component to show input editable grid which I have designed of multiple for loops. Each input element has property events like blur or click and value. The problem occurs when the number of rows in grid increases (above like 20-30 and each row has 12 columns) , the side filtering panel slows down and lags. Even of clicking the checkbox it takes around 3-4 sec to respond.
I have tried ChangeDetection.Onpush still no help

Answer (score 0):

To maximise performance in your case. You should only allow the element which is clicked should call the function. And for its child/parent elements try to prevent event propagation. So as to avoid running click handlers unnecessarily.

Refer this link for further reference to event propagation(bubbling) -
https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing